# Algorithm for drawing lines on the plane

Tags: .net, algorithm, graphics, image-processing

What is the algorithm for drawing line on the plane (pointwise), if it is not horizontal or vertical?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: In reality, of course, you'd rarely if ever use this these days - you leave it to your graphics API. But it's still occasionally worth knowing for other problems that turn out to be equivalent. For example, you need to update your integer time variable on every tick event - but the tick events come in at some non-integer interval. So long as that interval is rational, a Bresenhams based approach can maintain that time without cumulative error.

Comment: @Steve: there are plenty of uses even today... e.g. moving a player on a 2d grid, tracing a ray through a 3d grid (needs modification), etc...

Answer (score 4):

There is no 'pointwise' algorithm - points are infinitesimally small, so any algorithm based on points would take an infinite time to complete.

Instead, lines are drawn based on a notional pen width and calculating how many and what intensity of pixels that stroking the line with a pen would cover.

If you merely want to turn pixels on and off like it's the 1970s, then use one of the Brensenham's algorithm family.

Most modern computer graphics use anti-aliasing algorithms - either stroking, sub-sampling or exact pixel coverage - and sometimes parallel algorithms in the GPU ( for example drawing a line by projecting a thin rectangle onto the plane, or performing coverage calculations per pixel in parallel ).

Many graphics algorithms are based on Bezier curves; straight lines are just curves where the control points are in a line, so the algorithms for drawing them are the same, though may make a few optimisations.

Comment: +1 - but I've seen plenty of writing about graphics that uses the term "point" in place of "pixel". I agree "pixel" is better, but mathematicians don't have any special power to define the English language.